# React Native Gifted Chat text state not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to get the state to then push it to the server through an API call, but I cannot do this if the state is not getting defined.

I'm doing the following:

```
<GiftedChat
                        messages={this.state.messages}
                        renderUsernameOnMessage={true}
                        text={this.state.message}
                        onInputTextChanged={message => this.setState({ message })}
                        placeholder='Type your message here...'
                        renderBubble={props => {
                            return (
                                <Bubble
                                    {...props}
                                    textStyle={{
                                        right: {
                                            color: 'white',
                                        },
                                    }}
                                    wrapperStyle={{
                                        left: {
                                            backgroundColor: 'white',
                                        },
                                        right: {
                                            backgroundColor: 'black'
                                        }
                                    }}
                                />
                            );
                        }}
                        user={{
                            _id: this.state.userid,
                        }}
                        scrollToBottom
                        scrollToBottomComponent={() => (
                            <Ionicons name='ios-arrow-round-down' size={30} color='#000' />
                        )}
                        onSend={async () => {
                            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access');
                            const access = 'Bearer ' + token;
                            axios.post(`http://site.test/api/auth/send/group/${this.props.navigation.getParam('id')}`,
                                {
                                    message: this.state.message,
                                    groupId: this.props.navigation.getParam('id'),
                                },
                                {
                                    headers: {
                                        'Authorization': access,
                                    }
                                }).catch(err => {
                                    console.log(err);
                                })

                        }}
                    />
```

And on the `onSend` I'm doing the following:

```
onSend={async () => {
                    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access');
                    const access = 'Bearer ' + token;
                    axios.post(`http://site.test/api/auth/send/group/${this.props.navigation.getParam('id')}`,
                        {
                            message: this.state.message,
                            groupId: this.props.navigation.getParam('id'),
                        },
                        {
                            headers: {
                                'Authorization': access,
                            }
                        }).catch(err => {
                            console.log(err);
                        })

                }}
```

Am I doing something wrong over here?

Comment: I don't see you add onSend event to <GiftedChat />

Comment: and inside onSend, you need to re setState message

Comment: It's inside the <GiftedChat /> let me update the post.

Comment: updated, please check @CuongTranDuc

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

let try this, resetState for message which is passed to  , to update ui then send it to api call

```
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';

    onSend={(message) => {
      this.setState({
        message: GiftedChat.append(this.state.message, message)
      }, async () => {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access');
      const access = 'Bearer ' + token;
      axios.post(`http://site.test/api/auth/send/group/${this.props.navigation.getParam('id')}`,
          {
              message: this.state.message,
              groupId: this.props.navigation.getParam('id'),
          },
          {
              headers: {
                  'Authorization': access,
              }
          }).catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
          })
      })
    }}
```

Comment: "Cannot use await outside an async function"

Comment: `text.trim` is not a function it's telling me that now :/

Comment: I believe text.trim comes from the library itself

Comment: I updated my code. state message  is now an array, and try to remove text={this.state.message} in GiftedChat

Comment: dang, getting the same error... maybe the lib is broken?

Comment: My API works fine, the problem right now it's the front-end. The simulator throws me the error.

Comment: I think item in message array not contain text field

Comment: hmm? Couldn't understand what you just said